# Getting current date in Angular4

Tags: node.js, angular, angular4-forms

I have made input text boxes that select calendar and time using

`[(ngModel)]="toDateTransaction" useValueAsDate` .

Now I want to compare the selected date with current date (today's date). How to get that. I used

```
let currentDate = Date.now();
```

But its giving wierd output. I want to use in angular4 and node.js

Answer (score 1):

If you have a one-way binding to `ngModel` with `[]` syntax, changing the value of the domain model in the component class will set the value in the view. If you have a two-way binding with `[(ngModel)]` syntax (also known as 'banana-box syntax'), the value in the UI will always be synced back to the domain model in your class as well.
The `[(ngModel)]` syntax can only set a data-bound property. If you need to do something more or something different, you can write the expanded form
The `ngModel` data property sets the element's value property and the `ngModelChange` event property listens for changes to the element's value
 

HTML:

```
<input type="date" #ref [ngModel]="toDateTransaction" (ngModelChange)="onCompareDate(ref.value)">
```

Component:

```
onCompareDate(olddate):boolean{
    let date1 = new Date(olddate);
    let date2 = new Date();//your logic
          return date1.getFullYear() === date2.getFullYear() && date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() && date1.getDate() === date2.getDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you compare dates like this (example):

```
date1 = new Date();
date2 = new Date(date1);

date1.getDate() === date2.getDate()
```

Answer (score -1):

This should solve your problem, that's if at all I get your question clear enough.

```js
   angular.module('dateInputExample', [])
     .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.example = {
         value: new Date()
       };
     }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
   <label for="exampleInput">Pick a date:</label>
   <input type="date" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="toDateTransaction"
       placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" min="2018-01-01" max="2025-12-31" required />
</form>
```

You can get to read more form [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)